# Update one table from another based on condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the **project_progress.project_progress** column from another table **project_progress_detial.PPD_Progress** and make this query

```
UPDATE project_progress   
set progress_percent   =
(select PPD_Progress from project_progress_detial
where project_progress.project_id =project_progress_detial.PPD_ProjID and
project_progress.project_part_no = 1) table where
```

But the problem is it returning and error

> Sub query reutrns more than one row

Actually i want to shift my PPD_PRogress data into Project_Progress column which is in another table.

Comment: run this query and make sure that return only 1 row. 
select PPD_Progress from project_progress_detial
where project_progress.project_id =project_progress_detial.PPD_ProjID and
project_progress.project_part_no = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
    update project_progress 
    inner join project_progress_detial
    on project_progress.project_id=project_progress_detial.PPD_ProjID


    set project_progress.project_progress=project_progress_detial.PPD_Progress
where project_progress.project_part_no = 1
```

Comment: While a nicely formatted code block is great, it is best practice to include a little explanation of the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table1 a, 
       table2 b 
SET a.column=b.columm 
WHERE a.column1=b.column1
```

Comment: You can't have 2 tables in one `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Yes you can. Try the code. Then remove your down vote

Comment: Wow, you really can do that in `mysql` - I stand corrected. Downvote is not mine, btw.